# Sort two ArrayList correspondingly - Android

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists<> namely "Names" and "Ids" ("Names" contains names of customers while "Ids" contains ids of customers. Both of them are populated through a web-service. I add the "Names" to a Spinner and if I select any name in the Spinner, its corresponding Id is selected.

Now I want to show the "Names" sorted in the Spinner. But if I do that, I will lose the corresponding "Ids" that reside at the same position as the names once did, but since I changed the sequence of the "Names", it wouldn't be possible for me to get the corresponding Id against a name.

I want to sort both of them in such a way that if a name at position 3 is moved to position 10, its corresponding Id (which lied in a different ArrayList<> at position 3) should also be moved to position 10.

```
  ArrayList<String> Id = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> Name = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Create one new class like Data with two strings one is for names and another for id..now SORT the names with Data class.so no mismatch..

Comment: use a HashMap instead and sort it.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a class MyClass

```
class MyClass{
int Id ;
String Name;
}
```

and then create a single array list

```
ArrayList<MyClass> arr = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

and to sort create a custom comparator class

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<MyClass> {
@Override
public int compare(MyClass o1, MyClass o2) {
    return o1.Name.compareTo(o2.Name);
}
```

}

Your sorting code would be just about like you wrote:

```
Collections.sort(arr, new CustomComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparator is better Option

```
     Comparator<HashMap<String, String>> comparator = new Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>() {                                    
        @Override
        public int compare(HashMap<String, String> object1, HashMap<String, String> object2) 
        {       
                return object1.get("Id").compareToIgnoreCase(object2.get("Id"));
        }
};      
Collections.sort(groupData, comparator);
```

Id' being the key in the hash to sort on

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way, you can manage them with an `ArrayList` and an `HashMap` as follows...

```
  ArrayList<String> Name = new ArrayList<String>();
  Map<String, String> nameIdMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Where, in the HashMap, `key` will be `name` and `value` will `id`. So, whenever you need to get an `id` corresponding to a `name`, you can retrieve as follows...

```
nameIdMap.get(Name.get(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sorted TreeMap:

```
Map<String, Float> map = new TreeMap<String, String>(yourMap);
It will automatically put entries sorted by keys.
```